# Difference of sets with different amount of columns?

Tags: relations, relational-algebra

## Problem

When there exists two sets, R and S, and we take the [difference](https://www.thoughtco.com/difference-of-two-sets-3126580) R - S, we remove the elements from R that exist in S.

For cases where the number of columns are the same on both sides, such as the example below, this works fine:

[image]

## Question

However, what happens when R and S have a different amount of columns?

Comment: [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) Please put everything needed to ask your question in your post (using text for what can be given in text), not just at a link.

Comment: Relational algebra <> set algebra. So relational algebra difference <> set difference. Depending on the algebra, a relation is not necessarily characterizable as a set of tuples. There are many relational algebras. They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give operator definitions & your reference for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page. PS What do you mean, "what happens"? You can't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall, the difference operation requires the two relations involved to be compatible, implying that they should have the same number of columns.

Quoting from Wikipedia about [relational algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra)

> For set union and set difference, the two relations involved must be
>   union-compatible—that is, the two relations must have the same set of
>   attributes.